# How to create a JSON string in Visual Basic using json.net?

Tags: json.net

I'm using json.net to parse a JSON text. I got a `JObject` now:

```
Dim json_text As String
json_text = "{" & Chr(34) & "Venue" & Chr(34) & ": {" & Chr(34) & "ID" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "JSON" & Chr(34) & "}}"
Console.WriteLine(json_text)
Dim json As JObject
json = JObject.Parse(json_text)
Console.WriteLine(json.SelectToken("Venue").SelectToken("ID"))
```

Now I want to do the opposite and create a JSON text from the JSON variable.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any solution out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
    Imports Newtonsoft.Json

    Dim json_text As String
    json_text = "{" & Chr(34) & "Venue" & Chr(34) & ": {" & Chr(34) & "ID" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "JSON" & Chr(34) & "}}"
    Console.WriteLine(json_text)
    Dim json As JObject
    json = JObject.Parse(json_text)
    Console.WriteLine(json.SelectToken("Venue").SelectToken("ID"))

    Dim json_string As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json,
                   Formatting.Indented, New JsonSerializerSettings())

    Console.WriteLine(json_string)
```

This results in:

```
{"Venue": {"ID":"JSON"}}
JSON
{
  "Venue": {
    "ID": "JSON"
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems we can do the same thing with:

    `Console.WriteLine(json.ToString)`